# Problems fitting vocabulary in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have a directory full of `.txt` files (documents). First I `load` the documents and strip some parenthesis and remove some quotes, so the documents looks as follows, for example:

```
document1:
is a scientific discipline that explores the construction and study of algorithms that can learn from data Such algorithms operate by building a model

document2:
Machine learning can be considered a subfield of computer science and statistics It has strong ties to artificial intelligence and optimization which deliver methods
```

So I'm loading the files from the directory like this:

```
preprocessDocuments =[[' '.join(x) for x in sample[:-1]] for sample in load(directory)]


documents = ''.join( i for i in ''.join(str(v) for v
                                              in preprocessDocuments) if i not in "',()")
```

Then I'm triying to vectorize `document1` and `document2` in order to create a training matrix as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(analyzer='word')
X = HashingVectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
X.toarray()
```

Then this is the output:

```
    raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

How can I create a vector representation given this?. I thought that i was carrying the loaded files in `documents` but it seems that the documents can not be fitted.

Answer (score 2):

What are the contents of `documents`? [It looks like](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.fit_transform) it is supposed to has to be a list of either file names or strings with the tokens. Also, you are supposed to call the fit_transform using the object, not like a static method, i. e. `vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)`.

For example, this worked here:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
documents=['this is a test', 'another test']
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(analyzer='word')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, when I print `documents` I obtain the following:`[a very large text][another very large text][a third very large text]`, three lists that represent the 3 .txt files I have in the directory, any suggestion from here?.

Comment: Yes, your `documents` should be a list where each element is a string with a tokenized document. Something like: `documents=['word_1_doc_1 word_2_doc_1 word_3_doc_1', 'word_1_doc_2 word_2_doc_2 ...', 'word_1_doc_3, word_2_doc_3 ...']`. If you do something like `documents=[' '.join(ii) for ii in documents]`, it might do the trick.